# SimpleCursorTreeAdapter проблема с обновлением данных

Tags: cursor, android

Люди помогите пожалуйста, бьюсь уж 2-й день.

У меня наблюдается странное поведение при обновлении  данных в SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.
Есть два Activity: ActivityButton и ActivityTreeAdapter.
Первым запускается ActivityButton из которого мы можем перейти в ActivityTreeAdapter.
Функционал ActivityTreeAdapter следующий: Возможность в ручную создать группы, а в группы распихивать элементы.

Проблема заключается в следующем:
Если я **первый раз в группу**  записываю элемент, то при попытке развернуть группу приложение сваливается в ошибку "**java.lang.NullPointerException**"(при этом данные все записываются).

При повторном заходе в ActivityTreeAdapter все становиться нормально, я вижу только что созданную мной группу, которая нормально разворачивается. При этом я нормально могу добавлять новые группы и элементы уже безо всяких ошибок.

Т.е можно сделать например так зайти в ActivityTreeAdapter создать группы, вернуться в ActivityButton и обратно в ActivityTreeAdapter где уже абсолютно нормально можно создавать вложенные элементы.

Предполагаю что проблема в обновлении курсора в программе он обновляется два раза: первый при создании группы, а второй при добавлении элемента в группу.

**Вот данные из LogicCat:**

- java.lang.NullPointerException
     android.widget.SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.bindView(SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.java:243)
     android.widget.SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.bindChildView(SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.java:262)
     android.widget.CursorTreeAdapter.getChildView(CursorTreeAdapter.java:250)
     android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:450)

**Вот DEBUG:**

- Thread [<1> main] (Suspended
     (exception NullPointerException))  
          ExpandableListView(ListView).layoutChildren()
         line: 1662 
          ExpandableListView(AbsListView).onLayout(boolean,
         int, int, int, int) line: 1147 
          ExpandableListView(View).layout(int,
         int, int, int) line: 7035  
          LinearLayout.setChildFrame(View,
         int, int, int, int) line: 1249 
          LinearLayout.layoutVertical() line:
         1125 
          LinearLayout.onLayout(boolean, int,
         int, int, int) line: 1042  
          LinearLayout(View).layout(int, int,
         int, int) line: 7035 
          FrameLayout.onLayout(boolean, int,
         int, int, int) line: 333 
          FrameLayout(View).layout(int, int,
         int, int) line: 7035 
          PhoneWindow$DecorView(FrameLayout).onLayout(boolean,
         int, int, int, int) line: 333  
          PhoneWindow$DecorView(View).layout(int,
         int, int, int) line: 7035  
          ViewRoot.performTraversals() line:
         1045 
          ViewRoot.handleMessage(Message)
         line: 1727 
          ViewRoot(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message)
         line: 99     Looper.loop() line: 123 
          ActivityThread.main(String[]) line:
         4627     Method.invokeNative(Object,
         Object[], Class, Class[], Class,
         int, boolean) line: not available
         [native method]
          Method.invoke(Object, Object...)
         line: 521  
          ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run()
         line: 868  
          ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line:
         626      NativeStart.main(String[])
         line: not available [native
         method]

**Вот код ActivityTreeAdapter:**

Answer (score 1):

Судя по логам валится в `bindView` - перехватите (`@override`) `bindView` и поставьте внутри него логи тогда станет понятно почему валится. `bindView` это место где полям курсора ставится в соответствие конкретный `View`. Скорее всего почему-то не подхватывается `View` из закрепленного лэйаута.